# Microsoft Power BI and ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, powerbi

Does anyone know a implementation case that involves PowerBI and ElasticSearch?

I was unable to find any proper documentation.

Answer (score 7):

We don't have an integration with Elastic Search right now.  I looked at the Elastic Search REST API.  It looks doable to use Power Query to pull data for specific queries into Excel or Power BI Designer. You can use the "From Web" source and put your well formed query into the box.  Power Query parses JSON so the responses should be understood. You would use Power Query's UI to get the columns from the response as you need.

Appreciate your considering Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

If you'd like to stay up to date with the Power BI developer story, you can register (http://solutions.powerbi.com/appsuggestion.html) or follow our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/)

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I will keep an eye on the blogs.

Comment: Is this still true (3 years later)?

Answer (score 0):

The Elasticsearch API does make this feel a very clean way to pull the data into PowerBi.

It's very easy to add a **web** type datasource for Elasticsearch's API (e.g. http://your_server:9200/your_index/_search),  and pass the Elasticsearch query DSL as JSON in the source Web.Contents..

Edit your data source in the advanced editor, and you can put your DSL query in the *jscontent*. Using aggregates lets you keep the number crunching up with Elasticsearch in the data layer, and data returned small.

Just make sure to double up those double-quotes to escape them. ^_^

```
let
    jscontent = "{
       ""query"": {
          ""match_all"": {}
        },
        ""size"": ""0"",
        ""aggs"": {
          ""tiles_nesting"": {
            ""nested"": {
              ""path"": ""tiles""
            },
            ""aggs"": {
              ""user_type_node"": {
                ""terms"": {
                  ""field"": ""tiles.data.user_type.keyword""
                },
                ""aggs"": {
                  ""count_diff_values"": {
                    ""value_count"": {
                      ""field"": ""tiles.data.user_type.keyword""
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }",
    
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("http://your_server:9200/your_index/_search",[
        Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/json"],
        Content=Text.ToBinary(jscontent) ])),
in
    Source
```